# I am having difficulty sorting a dictionary by value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I know there exist other questions on this topic; however, I have been unsuccessful in adapting those answers in to my code. What I need assistance with is sorting the dictionary in my second and third print functions that would sort the dictionary by the batting order, which is the middle value in the dictionary code, ex. ['DH', **6**, 299]. My code is as follows:

```
def main():
    print('Rays Starters','\n')
    starters = {'DeJesus': ['DH', 6, 299],
                'Loney': ['1B', 4, 222],
                'Rivera': ['C', 9, 194],
                'Forythe': ['2B', 5, 304],
                'Souza Jr': ['RF', 2, 229],
                'Longoria': ['3B', 3, 282],
                'Cabrera': ['SS', 7, 214],
                'Kiermaier': ['CF', 1, 240],
                'Guyer': ['LF', 8, 275]}
for key, value in starters.items():
    print(key, value)
print('\n')

print("Today's lineup", '\n')
for key, value in (starters.items()):
    print('Batting {}: {} {}, current avg: {}'.format(value[1], value[0], key, value[2]))
print('\n')

print('Lineup change', '\n')
del starters['DeJesus']
del starters['Rivera']
starters2 = {'Wilson': ['C', 9, 152], 'Bechham': ['DH', 6, 200]}
starters.update(starters2)
for key, value in starters.items():
    print('Batting {}: {} {}, curent avg: {}'.format(value[1], value[0], key, value[2]))    

main()
```

For reference, my current output is:

```
Rays Starters 

Forythe ['2B', 5, 304]
Loney ['1B', 4, 222]
Longoria ['3B', 3, 282]
Kiermaier ['CF', 1, 240]
Guyer ['LF', 8, 275]
Rivera ['C', 9, 194]
DeJesus ['DH', 6, 299]
Cabrera ['SS', 7, 214]
Souza Jr ['RF', 2, 229]


Today's lineup 

Batting 5: 2B Forythe, curent avg: 304
Batting 4: 1B Loney, curent avg: 222
Batting 3: 3B Longoria, curent avg: 282
Batting 1: CF Kiermaier, curent avg: 240
Batting 8: LF Guyer, curent avg: 275
Batting 9: C Rivera, curent avg: 194
Batting 6: DH DeJesus, curent avg: 299
Batting 7: SS Cabrera, curent avg: 214
Batting 2: RF Souza Jr, curent avg: 229


Lineup change 

Batting 5: 2B Forythe, curent avg: 304
Batting 9: C Wilson, curent avg: 152
Batting 4: 1B Loney, curent avg: 222
Batting 3: 3B Longoria, curent avg: 282
Batting 1: CF Kiermaier, curent avg: 240
Batting 8: LF Guyer, curent avg: 275
Batting 6: DH Bechham, curent avg: 200
Batting 7: SS Cabrera, curent avg: 214
Batting 2: RF Souza Jr, curent avg: 229
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sorted()` takes an argument, `key`, which is a function that returns the value on which to sort.

Try this:

```
def key_func(item):
    value = item[1]
    order = value[1]
    return order
for key, value in sorted(starters.items(), key=key_func):
    ...
```

Or, more simply:

```
for key, value in sorted(starters.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1]):
    ...
```

Comment: That worked beautifully. 
So the "x: x[1][1]", how does that know to call that specific value, and not the batting average #(ex. 300) which are much higher numbers in the code.

Comment: extracting the `key_func` is a great idea if you want to be able to write unittests. Guido made the lambda syntax ugly for a reason